# Change row color in Angular Material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I change the color of a material table row depending on a cell value.

I have this in my **HTML**:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="DateAdded">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Submission Time </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.DateAdded | date: 'medium'}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="StartDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Start Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.StartDate | date}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="EndDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> End Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.EndDate | date}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="IsGranted">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Granted </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"  [ngClass]="row.IsGranted ? 'make-green' : ''"> {{row.IsGranted}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Remarks">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Remarks </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color">
        <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" (click)="viewRemarks(row.Remarks)">Select</button>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" [ngClass]="{'make-green': row.IsGranted==true}"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
                </mat-row>
    </mat-table>

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

And my **CSS** :

```
.make-gold {
    background-color: gold
}
```

This produces the following result:
[image]

What I need is to change the background color of the whole row. Not just the cell. Thank you.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I assume that you want to apply `make-gold` class when `IsGranted` value is true. If this is the case, try this:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'make-gold': row.IsGranted }">
```

See also [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-highlight-row-on-conditions).

#### EDIT

There is also a shorthand syntax:

```
<mat-row ... [class.make-gold]='row.IsGranted' [class.another-class]="true">
```

Comment: @leopard What about cell color instead of full row color?

Comment: @user15122827 try the same on mat-cell

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" [ngClass]="{accent:true}">
```

In case you need to use `accent` or `primary` or `warn`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I wanted to change the row background color when the row id is 0. Here ngClass directive ([angular doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)) applies 'new-row' CSS class when the condition is true.

In table component

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="{'new-row': row.id == 0 }"></tr>
```

CSS

```
 .new-row {
        background-color: #eef2f5
  }
```